# Regex for $gme or gme with space or no space after or before it in python

Tags: python, regex

I want a regex that can find all $gme or gme. It should not find $gme or gme in a string like

> hello $gmee

or

> hello g$gme

So for example in a string such as

> Hello gme. Hey $gme. Hey $gmee. Hey gmee.

It should find only gme or $gme from the above string.

It must also find gme or $gme when there is no space before or after a string
For example

> $gme

or

> gme

I am writing a script that can count the number of times $gme or gme is mentioned in a string

So in a string like

> Hello gme. Hey $gme. Hey $gmee. Hey gmee.

Its mentioned only two times.

I hope its clear now.

Regex I have tried

```
\$gme$|\sgme\s|\sgme|^gme\S
```

[See the demo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcJXA.png).

The above one fails when there is no space before and after $gme or gme. And also it includes gmee and $gmee which I don't want to include.

Comment: Writing a script to ban $gme spam on wsb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use a mix of whitespace and word boundaries:

```php
(?<!\S)\$?gme\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zxc3PZ/1)

*Details*:

- `(?<!\S)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is no non-whitespace char immediately to the left of the current position (so, start of string or a whitespace must occur immediately on the left)
- `\$?` - an optional `$` char
- `gme` - a word
- `\b` - a word bounary.